# How to solve for $x$ when $x$ is in both the numerator and denominator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm terrible at solving equations. I can do simple things like $x=\frac{y}{2}$ but for example I'd like to solve for $x$ in the following equation

$$a=\frac{x(f+g)h+fgh2}{-x}$$

For example I tried these steps

Divide by $-x$:

$$a(-x)=x(f+g)h+fgh2$$

Now subtract $fgh2$:

$$a(-x)-fgh2=x(f+g)h$$

Now divide by $(f+g)h$:

$$\frac{a(-x)-fgh2}{(f+g)h}=x$$

But that's doesn't really help because $x$ is on both sides. I tried moving $x$ to the left by making it $=0$ but I was lost after that. Of course I'd like the solution but more than that I'd like to know how to think so I can solve the next one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me see if I can clarify.

When you re-arrange terms, you want *all* the x's to one side and *all* non-x's to the other.

Continuing from where you start
$$
a(-x)=x(f+g)h+fgh^2
$$
to get
$$
a(-x) - x(f+g)h = fgh^2$$
Now collect the coefficients of $x$
$$
x (-a -(f+g) h) = fgh^2$$

Now you can solve for $x$
$$
x = \frac{fgh^2}{(-a -(f+g) h)} = -  \frac{fgh^2}{(a +(f+g) h)}$$

Comment: Thanks. It's been so long since I've done this kind of stuff. Yes, I should have moved all $x$ to one side as soon as possible. I still would have gotten a little lost at the 'collect the coefficients of x' because my math logic is rusty. Need more practice.

Answer (score 2):

You could divide every term on the right side of the equation by $x$ to get

$$a = \frac{(f+g)h+\frac{1}{x}fgh^2}{-1}.$$

Can you see where to go from here?

Comment: Hmmm, I got to $$\frac{a(-1)-(f+g)h}{fgh2}=\frac{1}{x}$$ but then I got lost again. I think I'm forgetting something fundamental.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer... the rule to remember is **all** or **nothing**. It is customary to keep $x$ on the left and all the others on the right.

Comment: wow, I'm an idiot (or forgetful). I can just flip both sides, which is the same answer user44179 gave.

Answer (score 1):

$$a=\frac{x(f+g)h+fgh2}{-x}$$

Think of $(f+g)h$ as some number $3$. Think of $fgh2$ as some other number $5$. You can think of $a$ as a number also, say $7$. How would you solve it then?

$$7=\frac{3x+5}{-x}$$

Multiply both sides as you did by $-x$

$$-7x=3x+5$$

$$-7x-3x=5$$

Only in your problem, at this point, you factor out the x:

$$(-7-3)x=5$$

$$x=\frac{5}{-7-3}$$

and then simplify. You can do your problem similarly.

Comment: That's helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Forget this question for a moment: how would you solve the equation below?

$$2x + 3 = 4x + 5$$

Comment: subtract $2x$ so $$3=2x+5$$ subtract $5$ so $$-2=2x$$ divide by 2 so $$-1=x$$. Hmmm I guess I'm not seeing the connection yet. I'll keep trying

Comment: I think I see your point. I needed to get $x$ to one side. I thought I knew that but I kept going too far before I did it which made things complicated. Thanks for your help.